# Настройка маппинга элементов

Tags: c#, automapper

Есть два класса, для которые нужно сначала сохранить в некоторых DTO-объектах, которые полностью повторяют структуру этих классов, а затем снова развернуть в исходное состояние:

```
public class Element
{
    public ParentItem Item { get; set; }
}

public class ParentItem
{
    public Element Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Метод, который создает исходные данные:

```
static Element[] CreateElements()
{
    var element2 = new Element();
    return new[]
    {
        new Element(new ParentItem(element2)),
        element2,
        new Element()
    };
}
```

Конфигурация автомаппера и маппинг созданных элементов:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ElementDto, Element>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentItemDto, ParentItem>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Element, ElementDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<ParentItem, ParentItemDto>();

var elements = CreateElements();
var mappedElements = elements
    .Select(_ => Mapper.Map(_, typeof(Element), typeof(ElementDto)))
    .OfType<ElementDto>()
    .ToArray();
```

Далее проверяем, сохранилась ли структура элементов после маппинга:

```
foreach (var element in mappedElements)
{
    Console.WriteLine(mappedElements.Any(e => e?.Item?.Parent == element));
}
```

Этот код трижды выводит `False`. Из чего следует, что для объекта `element2` из метода `CreateElements` было сделано две копии. Первая при копировании перечня элементов, вторая при копировании `ParentItem.Parent`.

Как нужно настроить маппинг, чтобы в `ParentItem.Parent` не создавалась еще одна копия элемента?

Comment: В официальной рассылке сказано, что для этого достаточно переопределить Equals/GetHashCode: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/automapper-users/Tgrh7Vb0vZ4. Я попробовал, не помогло. Возможно вам стоит задать вопрос в этот же лист.

Comment: Вижу, что вы задали там вопрос. Не забудьте потом сюда решение разместить :).

Comment: @andreycha, обязательно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как выяснилось, AutoMapper подобные штуки не умеет разруливать. Т.е. копии объектов все равно будут создаваться.

Так что подобные зависимости придется разруливать руками. В данном случае можно сделать примерно следующее. Во-первых, при маппинге не копировать всю цепочку элементов, а скопировать только `Element` и его `Item`. Остальная часть цепочки копируется с предварительными проверками на дублирование элементов.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Item, ItemDto>()
    .ForMember(_ => _.Element, _ => _.Ignore());
```

Во-вторых, нужно запоминать элементы, которые уже были скопированы и заполнять `Item` вручную.

```
static IEnumerable<ElementDto> MapElements(Element[] elements)
{
    var elementToDtoMap = new Dictionary<Element, ElementDto>();

    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        MapElement(element, null, elementToDtoMap);
    }

    return elementToDtoMap.Select(_ => _.Value);
}

static void MapElement(Element element, ItemDto parentItem, Dictionary<Element, ElementDto> elementToDtoMap)
{
    ElementDto elementDto = null;
    if (elementToDtoMap.TryGetValue(element, out elementDto))
         return;

    elementDto = Mapper.Map<ElementDto>(element);
    elementToDtoMap.Add(element, elementDto);

    if (parentItem != null)
    {
        parentItem.Element = elementDto;
    }

    if (element.Item != null)
    {
        MapElement(element.Item.Element, elementDto.Item, elementToDtoMap);
    }
}
```

Таким образом, можно добиться желаемого результата. Код, конечно, будет сильно зависить от конкретного случая. Но общий принцип примерно такой.

Answer (score 0):

> Есть два класса, для которые нужно сначала сохранить в некоторых DTO-объектах, которые полностью повторяют структуру этих классов, а затем снова развернуть в исходное состояние

Если DTO используются в качестве неизменяемого типа (т.е. его поля/свойства - readonly), то в такой ситуации вместо копирования данных проще использовать интерфейc и передавать его между модулями.

```
public interface ElementDto {
    int Value { get; }
}

class Module1 {
    static public void Process(ElementDto dto) {
        // тут можно только получить значения из dto 
    }
}

class Module2 {

    class Element : ElementDto {
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    static public void Run() {
        var e = new Element() { Value = 123 };
        Module1.Process(e);  // передаем ElementDto -- его Value - readonly 
    }
}
```

В этом решении есть один "минус". В методе Module1.Process, несмотря на то, что Element скрыт за интерфейсом ElementDto, при помощи рефлексии можно изменить значение Element.Value, так:

```
dto.GetType().GetMethod("set_Value").Invoke(e, new object [] { 321 });
```